# Google Pub/Sub | Spring Cloud GCP | Publishing by enabling ordering key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-gcp

I want to publish a message with ordering enabled via `pubSubTemplate`. On building `PubsubMessage`  and publishing it via `pubSubTemplate` I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot publish a message with an ordering key when message ordering is not enabled in the Publisher client. Please create a Publisher client with setEnableMessageOrdering(true) in the builder.`

I am using Spring Cloud GCP starters dependencies for integration with Google Pub/Sub.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I am using `PubSubTemplate` to publish the messages. Here is the definition of `PubSubTemplate`.

```
  @Bean
  public Credentials credentials() throws IOException {
    return GoogleCredentials.fromStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(credentialsFilePath)));
  }

  @Bean
  public PublisherFactory publisherFactory(Credentials credentials) {
    return new DefaultPublisherFactory(() -> projectId);
  }

  @Bean
  public SubscriberFactory subscriberFactory(Credentials credentials) {
    return new DefaultSubscriberFactory(() -> projectId);
  }

  @Bean
  public PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate(
      PublisherFactory publisherFactory, SubscriberFactory subscriberFactory) {
    return new PubSubTemplate(publisherFactory, subscriberFactory);
  }
```

Comment: I checked in the code, it does not work with default publisher factory. You have to create your own custom factory for that parameter. Or open a feature request to ask for a change in the default publisher factory.

Comment: That means, there is no way to enable ordering while publishing via pubSubTemplate. I'll have to use com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher to achieve it.

Comment: Correct, or you have to build your own factory. By inheritance, shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, I was using the older dependencies which didn't support publishing via `PubSubTemplate` by enabling `Ordering Key`.

On updating dependencies as below, I'm able to achieve it.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Ordering can be enabled at `PublisherFactory` level which is used to define `PubSubTemplate` bean like below -

```
  @Bean
  public PublisherFactory publisherFactory(Credentials credentials) {
    DefaultPublisherFactory factory = new DefaultPublisherFactory(() -> projectId);
    factory.setEnableMessageOrdering(true);
    factory.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials));
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate(
      PublisherFactory publisherFactory, SubscriberFactory subscriberFactory) {
    return new PubSubTemplate(publisherFactory, subscriberFactory);
  }
```

Now, messages can be sent by passing `orderingKey` in `PubSubMessage` object.

```
    pubSubTemplate.publish(topic,PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
        .setData(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(payload))
        .setOrderingKey(orderingKey)
        .build());
```